# how to calculate all addToCart product total price in react redux

Tags: html, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

```
<div className='container py-4 my-5'>
  {item.length === 0 ? (
    <p>
      cart is empty, <NavLink to='/'>continoue shopping</NavLink>
    </p>
  ) : (
    item.map((cart) => {
      return (
        <div className='row py-5 border-bottom'>
          <>
            <div className='col-md-4'>
              <img
                src={cart.image}
                alt=''
                style={{ width: '100%', height: '300px', objectFit: 'contain' }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className='col-md-4'>
              <h3> {cart.title} </h3>
              <p className='lead'> {cart.description} </p>
              <p>Quantity: {cart.qty}</p>
              <strong className='lead fw-bold'>
                {' '}
                price: {cart.price * cart.qty}{' '}
              </strong>

              <div className='mt-4'>
                <button
                  className='btn btn-outline-dark me-4'
                  onClick={() => Decrement(cart)}
                >
                  <i className='fa fa-minus'></i>
                </button>
                <button
                  className='btn btn-outline-dark'
                  onClick={() => addIncrement(cart)}
                >
                  <i className='fa fa-plus'></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        </div>
      );
    })
  )}

  <div className='checkout'>
    <h2 className='my-4'>total price: </h2>
    <button className='btn btn-outline-dark px-5 py-2 green'>Checkout</button>
  </div>
</div>;
```

**I'm showing products in cart component using simple react, im just confused how to calculate total price of all cart product. its an react redux based application, I'm getting data from "useSelector in cart component through map function. is there any possibility to just calculate total price of all cart which i just add."**

Comment: Well as far as I can see from the code you shared you have `item` array that holds your cart. So use a for loop or reduce function to sum up the item's total price.

Comment: I think this value should come from the backend as you should not keep business logic in the frontend eg. Total amount may contain Taxes then in that case you have to keep the tax percentage as well and may be in future tax rate got change then you have to update it again.
So according to me this this should come from the backend in the /cart api.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` function to calculate the total price:

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0.0);

useEffect(() => {
    // Update total when item qty changes
    const newTotal = item.reduce((a,b) => (a.qty * a.price) + (b.qty * b.price));
    setTotal(newTotal)
}, [item]) 

...

<div className='checkout'>
    <h2 className='my-4'>total price: {total}</h2>
    <button className='btn btn-outline-dark px-5 py-2 green'>Checkout</button>
</div>
```